# How to make Android NOT count ListView's section headers?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using this list: https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/ListviewFilter, bu I found that when I have three rows in 'A' section and two in 'B' section - that first row in 'B' section has position 5 instead of 4. How can I force it to not count section headers?

```
 public int getRealPosition(int position){
    int sectionHeaders = 0;
    for (Integer i : mListSectionPos){
        if (position > i){
            sectionHeaders += 1;
        }
    }
    Log.i("ASD-truepos", String.valueOf(sectionHeaders));

    return position - sectionHeaders;
}
```

Comment: 'that first row in 'B' section has position 5 instead of 4.'. You mean: instead of 3.

Comment: Hello jean d'arme i am facing same issue. How did you overcome this ? please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to override the method `getCount()` from the `PinnedHeaderAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListItems.size();
}
```

You could return `mListItems.size() - 1` or do some calculations in order to know if the header is present or not and then return the correct value.

If you do this override, do it in the moment in which you instantiate the class or you could add a Java class that extends `PinnedHeaderAdapter`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to count number of section headers so I can minus number of them fro mListItems.size()

Comment: Note this method inside onScroll: `@Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
  if (view instanceof PinnedHeaderListView) {
   ((PinnedHeaderListView) view).configureHeaderView(firstVisibleItem);
  }
 }`. This shows a little the way. Count all the elements on the list (asking for the size of the list) and then count manually all the items on the list that are instance of PinnedHeaderListView. Then make the rest and you'll get the correct size.

Comment: I came up with some idea, but it doesn't work. I don't know from which place it takes position...

Comment: Ok, I updated my question: this one is a solution. I call it on adapter from activity.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to calculate:

```
int total=listView.getCount()-listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
```